# Combining two Google Analytics scripts

Tags: google-analytics

I´m trying to combine two Google Analytics scripts, _trackEvent and _trackPageview.
My questions is, how do I write this in one single script?

This works fine

```
<a href="www.link.com" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button', 'Category', 'Product']);"Text</a>
```

Now I need to add following script below:

```
<a href="www.link.com" onClick="pageTracker._trackPageview(‘/virtual/page/productA’);">Text</a>
```

Does anyone have a working solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

---

See my code below, an event is created correctly in Google Analytics, also a content page is created, example "/virtual/products/abc", but it dosen´t effect goal tracking in GA at all, which is odd.

If I remove _trackEvent code, the _trackPageview works, so I guess Im still struggling how to combine this two Analytics events with HTML correctly.

```
<a href="url" target="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button', 'Category', 'Product', 100]); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/virtual/products/abc/']);">Link text</a>
```

Thanx in advance,
/Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

[One Push, Multiple Commands](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#MultipleCommands)

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button', 'Category', 'Product'],['_trackPageview', ‘/virtual/page/productA’]);
```